# How to force the user to draw on certain elements if there are images in the layout

Tags: ux-field, color, contrast, color-blindness, ease-of-use

[image: mockup]

Well, I ran into the problem of distinguishability of content in a mobile application. In fact, there are a huge number of pictures on the page (movie poster, preview of the film as a picture). A lot of information is actually important, so it is made very contrast. And everything would be fine if it were not for the presence of pictures, which can be either unsaturated or very saturated, which is why I fear that everything can confuse the user. Although the main action (view from last place) is always at the bottom right in the form of a Floating Action Button (Which is actually not the best thing to do, but I just don't really know, what could be better and the same time consistent).

Comment: So what are you trying to draw their attention towards?

Comment: @NicolasHung Well, the most important thing is to let user find the "Play" button to continue watch serial/film or whatever it is. But at the same time, someone needs to just choose an episode. So, I don't really know what to rely on better. No, of course, often the user decides to continue to watch the show from the place where he finished, but, on the other hand, it can be played differently.For example, you can make it so that the user can do the same at the very beginning when the application is turned on.

Comment: @NicolasHung However, I don’t know how good this step is, because sometimes I myself first look at all the episodes, and then choose the right one. For example, if I already watched the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

The first scenario allows the user to easily find the continue playing button in the banner, while also indicating your progress in each episode via a progress bar.

The second scenario is when someone as finished watching the series. Therefore all progress bars are full.

As for image overload, I don't see it as an issue. Make sure not having autoplaying videos, only static images. It's just like browsing any e-commerce product listing or Netflix app.

Also, the screenshot provided looks like longer than a phone screen, so it might also be contributing to the content overload concern.

[image]

Comment: Well, that was... pretty easy! Thanks a lot, I think I've got this!